# python filtering a csv file by the coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to filter accidents in an area by the coordinates. ChatGPT says that I should do like this:

```
def filterAccidentsByBounds():
    # Filter bike accident DataFrame by the given bounds
    df_bikeAccidents_h = df_bikeAccidents.loc[
        (df_bikeAccidents['Latitude'] >= 52.302885) &
        (df_bikeAccidents['Latitude'] <= 52.453221) &
        (df_bikeAccidents['Longitude'] >= 9.584375) &
        (df_bikeAccidents['Longitude'] <= 9.902979)
    ]
    
    # Print the number of bike accidents in Hannover
    print("Number of bike accidents in Hannover:", len(df_bikeAccidents_h))
    
    return df_bikeAccidents_h

df_bikeAccidents_h = filterAccidentsByBounds()
```

But I would like to do it with an if loop like this:

```
def filterAccidentsByBounds():
    #filter bike accident dataframe by the given bounds
    #df_bikeAccidents_h = ...
    #XGCSWGS84        YGCSWGS84
    #print number of bike accidents in Hannover
    
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    
    df_bikeAccidents_h = df_bikeAccidents
    if df[[XGCSWGS84]] <= 52.453221 and df[[XGCSWGS84]] >= 52.302885:
        if df[[YGCSWGS84]] <= 9.902979 and df[[YGCSWGS84]] >= 9.584375
    
    
    return df_bikeAccidents_h

df_bikeAccidents_h = filterAccidentsByBounds()
```

Problem is I don't know what to write in the if loop. Can anyone help me with that?

I've tried to filter the accidents by the coordinates with an if loop but due to my lack of python skills I don't know what to write in the `if` statement.

Comment: 1. `if` is not a loop. 2. Why? the suggested code is far more performant. 3. We have no idea what `XGCSWGS84` and `YGCSWGS84` are. Show some [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take look at [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples) consider following example, say I want print x and y where y is greater or equal x, then I could do that following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4,5],"y":[5,4,3,2,1]})
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.y >= row.x:
        print(row.x, row.y)
```

gives output

```
1 5
2 4
3 3
```